# How to pass a pandas dataframe to R without using csv/feather/parquet files?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am using pandas v1.

Say

```
from siuba.data import mtcars
df = mtcars.copy(deep=True)
```

and I have

`rpy2`, how do I pass `df` into my R session without going through an external file such as csv/feather/parquet?

These solutions don't work any more [Rpy2: pandas dataframe can't fit in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800556/rpy2-pandas-dataframe-cant-fit-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `pyper`

```
import pandas as pd
from siuba.data import mtcars
from pyper import *
r = R(use_pandas=True)
df = mtcars.copy(deep=True)

r.assign("rdf", df)
r.get("head(rdf, 2)")
#   mpg cyl disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs  am  gear    carb
#0  21.0    6   160.0   110 3.9 2.620   16.46   0   1   4   4   
#1  21.0    6   160.0   110 3.9 2.875   17.02   0   1   4   4
```